# google test framework over TI compiler

Tags: c++, c, googletest

I am currently trying to compile google test framework over Code Composer studio using compiler "TI v5.1.8" whereas I am able to compile the framework using the same software but with compiler "GNU v4.7.4".

By using compiler "TI v5.1.8" I get errors like "sys/types.h" is missing and even if I bypass it (making an empty header file with the same name) than I get "regex.h" is missing.

As anyone tried compiling google test framework with compiler "TI v5.1.8" using Code composer studio? I shall be very thankful for the help.

Comment: why the c tag. C++ is not the same as C. please chose one

Comment: [We had similar question recently for the IAR compiler.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34258428/694733) I guess the GoogleTest framework is not really that portable library.